# BE6k Restricted and Unrestricted

Tags: cisco

i'm new here and i have little experience in Cisco Collaboration environment. Now i just want to know the difference between BE6k Restricted and Unrestricted deployment ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

These are export restricted versus unrestricted. If they're going to be operating in countries that have U.S. export restrictions placed against them, you'd have to use the restricted option. If you're only operating in the U.S., unrestricted is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Encryption.  It is illegal to export encryption technologies to some countries, so Cisco makes one without encryption.  With Cisco, the top level part number usually denotes this.  /K8 is unrestricted and /K9 means it includes encryption capabilities.